# Multiple capture groups - all optional

Tags: regex, optional-parameters, regex-group

I know this (or similar) has been asked a hundred times - but I really need help now :D
The strings the regex should match.

Note: `n` is in the range of `INTEGER_MIN - INTEGER_MAX`

```
{number}
{number(1-n)}
{number(1-n,-n-n)}
{number(1-n,-n-n,0-n)}
```

If the pattern matches it should result in 3 seperate capture groups, with this results.
All groups should be optional - so that if request in for example Java they return null.

```
1: 1-n
2: -n-n
3: 0-n
```

What I've tried:

```
\{number(?:\(([1-9])(?:(?:,)([0-9])){0,2}\))?\}
```

This obviously isn't right and is only containing 2 groups (`m.groupCount()`)

Comment: What do you mean by "there shouldn't be a specific limit for that number"? Could you give examples of what should match?

Comment: @Jerry `{number(1,-4,11111)}` as well as `{number(2322,231123,0)}`  should match. The numbers given shouldn't be lower than `INTEGER_MIN` and greater than `INTEGER_MAX`. I'll update the question to represent this.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, so you want to do some calculations while you do regex o_o ?

Comment: I got a given placeholder "{number(..,..,..)}". This placeholder can have up to 3 parameters - none is required! Afterwards each parameter is taken into account for a dynamic replacement which is done in my java code. I could use 4 seperate patterns - but I'm sure 1 will do it.

Comment: @DennisFischer the `n-n+1-n-n-n-n+-1` part is confusing. So what you want is 3 placeholders, all optional, they are all digits, and they can be negative numbers ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Correct. 3 "parameters", all optional, all numbers, 1st one at least 1 or greater. 3rd one at least 0 or greater. No limitations on 2nd parameter.

Comment: So [here](http://regex101.com/r/yI1jL1)'s what I came up with, hope this is what you wanted ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Hey thank you. This isn't the exact solution but I could use parts of it to combine it to the final solution of Jerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, from what I deduced, I would do this:

```
\{number(?:\((\-?\d+)(?:\,(\-?\d+))?(?:\,(\-?\d+))?\))?\}
```

Then carry out operations on the captured groups to valid the range of the integers such as...

[Pseudo code since I don't know what language you are using]

```
captured integers = "capture1", "capture2", "capture3"
if{("capture1" < "capture2" && "capture1" > "capture3") ||
   ("capture1" > "capture2" && "capture1" < "capture3")} {

    Do something

} else {

    Do something else; like reject or throw error

}
```

Comment: Doesn't match `{number(1)}` and `{number(1,-12)}`. I'm using java. Too bad I know what I got to change - but failing as always with regex....

Comment: @DennisFischer Oh, those are to be optional as well? Edited the regex. [And tested](http://www.regex101.com/r/zV5iY6).

Comment: That's almost it. For my usage I added number limitation to it:
`\{number(?:\(([1-9]\d*)(?:\,(\-?\d+))?(?:\,([0-9]\d*))?\))?\}`

Comment: @DennisFischer `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` =P

Comment: That's correct. I'll change that. But the minus was unwanted :D